# Detect cname of the subdomain using php

Tags: php, nginx

I have a php site *.example.com (wildcard subdomain)

```
<?php 
$subdomain = array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
echo $subdomain ;
?>
```

And if i visit `sample.example.com`, i will get `$subdomain` as `sample`.

But if we add a CNAME for a website `sub.example2.com` with `sample.example.com`, here i get the `$subdomain` as `sub`. But I need to get the `$subdomain` as `sample`.

How do i do this?

Comment: The only thing that PHP can see is what the browser actually sends, and the browser doesn't know that one domain name is a CNAME of another. You'll have to manage that in your own code. So you could say if the HTTP_HOST is `sub.example2.com` then set it to `sample.example.com` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the all DNS records details as follows:

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("sample.example.com", DNS_ANY);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Then, find the type=CNAME in associative array

Comment: I don't see any CNAME records there. But can see A records, AAA records

Comment: Try to replace DNS_ANY with DNS_CNAME and check.

Comment: Yeah works fine, if the CNAME domain is not proxied on Cloudflare.